# Access to Heart Rate data from microsoft-band with iOS SDKs

Tags: ios, objective-c, microsoft-band

I'm having trouble getting heart rate data from microsoft-band. It appears on my iOS app that the heart rate text label won't change. (`CoreBluetooth` frame has been added).

```
if (self.client && self.client.isDeviceConnected){
   [self output:@"Starting Heart Rate updates..."];
   [self.client.sensorManager startHeartRateUpdatesToQueue:nil errorRef:nil withHandler:^(MSBSensorHeartRateData *heartRateData, NSError *error) {
        self.heartRateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Heart Rate: %d bpm", heartRateData.heartRate];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing heart rate data from the Band requires a one-time user consent. The following API can be used to request and check user consent:

```
/**
 * Check user consent for heart rate.
 * @return MSBSensorUserConsent Returns a MSBSensorUserConsent value based on user consent.
 */
 - (MSBUserConsent)heartRateUserConsent;

/**
 * Request user consent for heart rate.
 * @param completion Completion block to invoke with the user response.
 */
 - (void)requestHRUserConsentWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL userConsent, NSError *error))completion;
```

Sample code for above API can be found in the [Band SDK documentation](http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) (Section 2.4.1.2).